# "Unrecognized selector" exception during GDB recursiveDescription

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gdb

I keep getting an unrecognized selector exception while running recursiveDescription with GDB in Xcode. Specifically, while stopped at a breakpoint, I'm entering the following in GDB:

```
po [[self view] recursiveDescription]
```

And getting the following exception:

```
-[UILabel length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
```

I have no idea what label(s) might be causing this or how to go about investigating further, let alone fixing it. Presumably recursiveDescription's implementation includes [UILabel length] calls, but what would cause my labels to break it? (My UI is pretty straightforward, not doing anything out of the ordinary with labels or anything else).

Would really appreciate any ideas or tips. Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like something is being released before it should - are you using ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: All under ARC, with strong pointers where necessary

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this? Seeing the same thing.

Comment: Wish I could tell you but I don't really remember haha. I'm pretty sure I never solved it though, but also have yet to experience this issue since

Answer (score 0):

Under **"Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes..."**, select the scheme you used to run the app.

Select **"Run"** on the left side, **"Diagnostics"** on the right panel and uncheck **"Enable Zombie Objets"**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with add exception break point in xcode. Whenever exception throw then breakpoint will stop at that line so you can easily get idea where is the issue in you code.